# R not being able to find the file despite being in correct directory

Tags: r

I have question regarding a project I have to do about a health student study. I cannot import the csv file via read.csv or read.csv2 despite having transformed all files to csv and being in the correct folder.
Here are the command lines:

```
setwd ("C:/Users/fek/Desktop/Analyse i-Share")
getwd()
TA<-read.csv2(file=Biobanque.csv, header=TRUE, sep=",", dec=",", fill=TRUE)
```

And here are the results in the console window:

```
setwd ("C:/Users/fek/Desktop/Analyse i-Share")

getwd()
```

[1] "C:/Users/fek/Desktop/Analyse i-Share"

```
TA<-read.csv2(file=Biobanque.csv, header=TRUE, sep=",", dec=",", fill=TRUE)
```

[1] Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
objet 'Biobanque.csv' introuvable

To translate from french, it says it can't find the file!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is just what it says.  By omitting the quotes around "Biobanque.csv", R thinks you are talking about an **object whose name is Biobanque.csv**. And R is confused because of course you have not created an object by that name.

Comment: This is correct - the error message states that R cannot find the *object* 'Biobanque.csv', not that it cannot find the *file* 'Biobanque.csv' (which would give the error "No such file or directory").